# how to do if contion check with variable (true or false) inside django template

Tags: django

how to do if contion check with variable (true or false) inside django template

```
<select id="company_id" name="company_id" class="form-control " >

                    <option value="">Select Company  {{company_id}}</option>
                    {% for row in brands %}

                    {% if row.id == company_id %} 

                        <option value="{{ row.id }}" >{{ row.title }} </option>
                    {% else %}

                       <option value="{{ row.id }}" selected>{{ row.title }} </option>

                    {% endif %}

                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

let us assume you have model and in that with other field you have a boolean field true in that and you want to check that boolean field is true or false if true pass this heading or if false pass this heading then you have to
do something like this

model

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and then in you template while your fetching modeldata in template

```
{% for user in users %}
{{user.first_name}}
{{user.last_name}}
{% if user.email_confirmed == True %}}
<h1>Authentic User</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>Not a authentic user</h1>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

i hope now you will got my point what i trying to explain

Comment: Thanks for your response but i need check if condition with variable

Comment: {% if row.id == company_id %}  company_id is variable, i need to check with brands loop

Comment: that pass it in a 'company_id'

Comment: No i got answer , my issue is company id comes like string so i change to integer